# Does Universal restriction fit in this row of description class in protege?

Tags: owl, protege, restriction

I have class `PlannedComposition` with two subclasses:

- `AsymmetricalComposition`
- `SymmetricalComposition`

They are closed with *covering axiom.* Because specific house can have only asymmetrical or symmetrical composition, but not both.

The class with individuals of houses are two types - one of them are symmetrical, the other one isn't.

My question is can I use universal restriction in the description of class `HouseTypeOne` (this one with symmetrical composition):

[image]

Comment: Yes, why not? It seems to be a normal modelling approach to me. Or perhaps you could rather say `hasComposition exactly 1 SymmetricalComposition` and declare the `hasComposition` property as a functional one.

Comment: Well, no,,, I'd say `hasComposition some Composition`.